# Solr Indexing - Manipulating the search result

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I am working with the TYPO3 Solr extension and I have some doubts regarding the solr result set manipulation.

I have added a special configuration for indexing some particular pages in my page tree. ie Pages that starts with the label "Expertise%" .I have managed to added this successfully . And the indexing is working successfully with our any trouble. But what I would like to achieve is that , I want to added parent page title to the search result.i.e

This is the page tree

```
|---- 1.00.100 (parent page)
|--Subpage 1
|--Subpage 2
|--Expertise
|--Test page`
```

And in the solr search result should be

1.00.100 - Expertise

Is this possible in TYPO3 Solr. Is there any hook or signalslot available to implement this?

Tried this ,But doesn't seems to work for me ?

```
  plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.expertise_offered = 1
  plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.expertise_offered {
    table = pages
          additionalWhereClause = doktype = 1 AND no_search = 0 AND title LIKE '%Expertise offered%'
            fields {
            title = title
            content = CONTENT
            parentPageTitle_stringS = CONTENT
            parentPageTitle_stringS {
                    table = pages
                    select {
                    selectFields = title
                    where = uid = ###pid###
                    }
                    markers {
                           pid.data = field:pid
                    }
        }
        content {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                selectFields = header, bodytext
            }
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                10 = TEXT
                10.field = header
                # This removes HTML tags
                11 = SOLR_CONTENT
                11.field = bodytext
            }
        }
        url = TEXT
        url.typolink.parameter = TEXT
        url.typolink.parameter.field = uid
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need any hook or signal-slot. You can do it as follows:

1. Add the title of the parent page to your indexing configuration. There is no field for it, but you can dynamically add fields to SOLR documents. This is done by sending the data in a field which has a certain suffix, which determines the field type.

   For example: Setting the field `parentPageTitle_stringS` to the parent pages title in the indexing configuration creates a new stored, single-valued field of type `string` in the indexed document.

   Filling this field could look like this:

   ```
   plugin.tx_solr {
       index {
           queue {
               <yourindexconfigname> = 1
               <yourindexconfigname> {
                   table = pages

                   fields {
                       parentPageTitle_stringS = CONTENT
                       parentPageTitle_stringS {
                           # Build a query here to retrieve
                           # the parent page title.
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your template for search results, you can use the marker `###RESULT_DOCUMENT.parentPageTitle_stringS###` to retrieve the field.

The available field types can be found in `EXT:solr/Resources/Solr/typo3cores/conf/general_schema_fields.conf` from line 157 onwards (refering to version 3.0.0 here).

You should of course use a type other than `string` if you want to have the result indexed nicely.

Comment: `plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.expertise_offered = 1
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.expertise_offered {
 table = pages
 fields {
  title = title
  content = CONTENT
  parentPageTitle_stringS = CONTENT
  parentPageTitle_stringS {
   table = pages
   select {
    selectFields = title
           where = uid = ###pid###
   }
             markers {
                    pid.data = field:pid
             }
  }
  content {
   table = tt_content
   select {
    selectFields = header, bodytext
   }
   renderObj = COA
   renderObj {
   }
  }
 }
}`
I tried this , Doesnt seems to work ??

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem is, but it could be a missing `pidInList`-setting in the CONTENT object. Try to build that object outside of the solr config and print it in the frontend for debugging or something like that.